# discord.py send an embed in a specific channel with a slash command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, channel

Here is my problem: I was searching for how to send a message on a chosen channel with a slash command, but I didn't find a way to realize this project, and maybe help me with the color too. There is a part of my code :

```
@bot.tree.command(guild= discord.Object(id=1127167530184740954), name="embed", description="Create an embed!")
async def cr_embed(interaction: discord.Interaction, title: str, description: str, colour_: int, field: str, value: str, channel_: discord.app_commands.AllChannels):
    cr_embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description=description, colour=couleur)
    cr_embed.add_field(name=field, value=value, inline=False)
    await salon.send(embeds=[cr_embed], ephemeral=False)
```

If someone can help me about this that would be very helpfull ! Thanks !

Comment: After some research, I found how to clarify it, so first: Channel is a discord.TextChannel, to send message into a specific channel, and if you want a voice channel or something like that you just have to put discord.VoiceChannel etc.. For the color, I just found a way to use it into the embed, so I let it as a int, but in the field on the slash command, I put `0xFFFFFF` and it perfectly works, maybe you can just convert it !

Comment: Here is the code :

```@bot.tree.command(guild= discord.Object(id=1127167530184740954), name="embed", description="Crée un embed dans le salon choisis !")
async def cr_embed(interaction: discord.Interaction, title: str, description: str, couleur: int, field: str, value: str, salon: discord.TextChannel):
    cr_embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description=description, colour=couleur)
    cr_embed.add_field(name=field, value=value, inline=False)
    await salon.send(embeds=[cr_embed]):```
Hope it was helpfull !